# Istio Gateway and VirtualService issue with Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm using Istio 1.1.7 and tried the following Gateway and VirtualService to the Kubernetes Dashboard.

But I'm seeing the following:

```
kubectl -n kube-system logs -f kubernetes-dashboard-7cf9657c74-5fsmq
2019/05/31 15:53:04 http: TLS handshake error from 10.244.3.11:54392: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: default-ingressgateway
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:

  - hosts:
    - "*"
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP

  - hosts:
    - "*"
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: dashboard-virtualservice
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - default/default-ingressgateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/dashboard"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kubernetes-dashboard
        port:
          number: 443
```

NOTE: I've also tried change the Gateway Server-TLSOptions-TLSmode from `mode: SIMPLE` to mode `mode: PASSTHROUGH`, but `PASSTHROUGH` I just get `We can’t connect to the server` in my Browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think `PASSTHROUGH` should work, if you configure it properly. Here is an example that does something similar. https://istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/ingress-sni-passthrough/